# Prove that the set A of all those points that belong to infinitely many sets is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

Let ${E_{n}}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets of real numbers. Prove that the set $A$ of all those points that belong to infinitely many sets from the sequence ${E_{n}}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Is the proof similar to that of "Borel-Cantelli Lemma"? if yes what will be the difference? If no can anyone provide me with the proof please?

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} E_m$ and hence $A$ is measurable.

Comment: will its measure be zero?

Comment: Under the hypothesis of B_C Lemma, yes. In general no.

Comment: will the proof be similar to B_C lemma?

Comment: I can see that $A$ subset only from the intersections and unions you provide ..... could you please explain from where the equality came?

Comment: If $x$ belongs to the right side then for every $n$ there is at least one $m\geq n$ with $x \in E_m$. This implies that $x$ belongs to infinitely many of the $E_n$'s.